# How to get the data-lp attribute on my <li> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I need to get the data-lp and the class value using javascript?

the logic i want is this:

```
if (document.querySelector('li[data-lp="9"].disabled'))
        {
            $('li[data-lp="9"].disabled').append('<style>div{border: 1px solid red;}</style>');
        }
        else
        {
            remove the style i made above.
        }
```

I want to put an  under in this condition. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: A little search on google and I found a [nice guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) on hw to read an attribute from a DOM node.

Comment: `.getAttribute("data-lp");` (Above doc in english: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: guys i edited my question. can you help me to solve this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a complex selector, so you will need to use [querySelector<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

```js
var lp9 = document.querySelector('li[data-lp="9"].disabled');
lp9.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li data-lp="4" class="none">2</li>
    <li data-lp="9" class="disabled">3</li>
</div>
```

If you are using jQuery as your now edited question suggests, just do the entire thing in jQuery.

```js
var $lp9 = $('li[data-lp="9"]');
if($lp9.is('.disabled')){
    $lp9.append('<style>.div{border: 1px solid red;}</style>');
}else{
    $lp9.empty();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li data-lp="4" class="none">2</li>
    <li data-lp="9" class="disabled">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="div">Other Content</div>
```

Comment: Hi travis i think this code is fit on my need, what if i do this? if (document.querySelector('li[data-lp="9"].disabled'))

Comment: how can I add a css under this condition?

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday - Did you see the edit? Basically you would take the element and access its style properties to add css settings.

Comment: Hi buddy. i edited my question above. I need to create like that. a <style> tag under it.

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday - You could do that with a single append in jQuery, please see my edit.

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday - Please avoid changing questions, just ask new ones or ensure that the entire situation is properly represented when you first post. I included the response in the edit, but this will be the last edit I make here.